# LLVM Regular Expression

Tags: llvm

LLVM Regex::BasicRegex claims that its a en ERE Posix standard, but in my version which is 3.4

```
new Regex("[A-Za-z0-9]*ClassDecl", llvm::Regex::BasicRegex)
```

works but

```
new Regex("[A-Za-z0-9]+ClassDecl", llvm::Regex::BasicRegex)
```

does not.

Is that a bug?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation of `llvm::Regex::BasicRegex`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Regex.html#a79ae71c4eeaf1d835aa4106155fa2aaeae62480697e924b5793194a07ac798df4):

> By default, the POSIX extended regular expression (ERE) syntax is assumed.
>
> Pass this flag to turn on basic regular expressions (BRE) instead.

So the `BasicRegex` flag *disables* the extended syntax. If you want to use ERE syntax, *don't* pass the `BasicRegex` flag.